# Number of least significant '0' digits affects the value in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Can someone please explain the behavior of the following three numbers in Pandas? I'm trying to load the following values and have them correctly represented.

- 954081199.495100000000000    => 9954081199.4951
- 9449546861.291050000000000   => 9449546861.29105
- 9752031802.626950000000000   => 9752031802.62695

As the trailing 0s are removed the value as understood by Pandas changes. It seems as though the trailing digits are affecting the significance of the values. Simply truncating the value after the nth digit isn't feasible because the actual length of the non-zero values after decimal point isn't known.

Is there there something in Pandas that controls this behavior?
I've tried using the "c" engine but that gives the same output.

The data is being read from a text file.

Thanks.

```
Loading sample_1.txt
Row   : Raw Value                      : Pandas Value
    0 : 954081199.495100000000000      : 954081199.4950998
    1 : 954081199.49510000000000       : 954081199.4950998
    2 : 954081199.4951000000000        : 954081199.4950998
    3 : 954081199.495100000000         : 954081199.4951
    4 : 954081199.49510000000          : 954081199.4951
    5 : 954081199.4951000000           : 954081199.4951
    6 : 954081199.495100000            : 954081199.4951
    7 : 954081199.49510000             : 954081199.4951
    8 : 954081199.4951000              : 954081199.4951
    9 : 954081199.495100               : 954081199.4951
   10 : 954081199.49510                : 954081199.4951
   11 : 954081199.4951                 : 954081199.4951
   12 : 9449546861.291050000000000     : 9449546861.291044
   13 : 9449546861.29105000000000      : 9449546861.291044
   14 : 9449546861.2910500000000       : 9449546861.291046
   15 : 9449546861.291050000000        : 9449546861.291046
   16 : 9449546861.29105000000         : 9449546861.291048
   17 : 9449546861.2910500000          : 9449546861.291048
   18 : 9449546861.291050000           : 9449546861.291048
   19 : 9449546861.29105000            : 9449546861.291048
   20 : 9449546861.2910500             : 9449546861.29105
   21 : 9449546861.291050              : 9449546861.29105
   22 : 9449546861.29105               : 9449546861.29105
   23 : 9752031802.626950000000000     : 9752031802.626955
   24 : 9752031802.62695000000000      : 9752031802.626955
   25 : 9752031802.6269500000000       : 9752031802.626951
   26 : 9752031802.626950000000        : 9752031802.626951
   27 : 9752031802.62695000000         : 9752031802.626951
   28 : 9752031802.6269500000          : 9752031802.626951
   29 : 9752031802.626950000           : 9752031802.626951
   30 : 9752031802.62695000            : 9752031802.626951
   31 : 9752031802.6269500             : 9752031802.62695
   32 : 9752031802.626950              : 9752031802.62695
   33 : 9752031802.62695               : 9752031802.62695
Done
```

Code to produce the above output

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas

def main():
    file_name = 'sample_1.txt'
    print ('Loading ' + file_name)    
    content_df = pandas.read_csv(file_name, delimiter='|', header=None, engine='python', skipinitialspace=True,skiprows=0,skipfooter=0)
    num_rows = content_df.values.shape[0]

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        lines_list = f.read().split('\n')

    f.close()
    rowcount = 0
    print('Row   : Raw Value' + ' '*22 + ': Pandas Value')
    while rowcount < num_rows:
        value_list = lines_list[rowcount].split('|')
        print('{0:5d} : {1} : {2}'.format(rowcount, value_list[2].ljust(30, ' '), content_df.iloc[rowcount, 2]))

        # print('row: ' + str(content_df.iloc[rowcount, 1]) + ': ' + str(content_df.iloc[rowcount, 2]) + ': ' + str(value_list[2]))
        rowcount = rowcount +1

    print ('Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Note sure but is it possible that Pandas doesn't encode your values on enough bits and that it fails to have a good precision ?

Comment: i get the same effect when i try to convert a string using powers of 10 calculations in float.  the final divide in the conversion is dividing by a big power of 10 in float which is larger with more appended digits. this is less accurate because higher powers of 10 cannot be precisely represented in float.  using ints to do the conversion would work.  float() seems to work right.  pandas might be doing the conversion badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is configurable using the 'c' engine, but with with the float_precision option set to 'high':  float_precision='high'.

Many thanks.

Reference: [Git Hub Issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17154)

```
Loading sample_1.txt
Row   : Raw Value                      : Pandas Value
    0 : 954081199.495100000000000      : 954081199.4951
    1 : 954081199.49510000000000       : 954081199.4951
    2 : 954081199.4951000000000        : 954081199.4951
    3 : 954081199.495100000000         : 954081199.4951
    4 : 954081199.49510000000          : 954081199.4951
    5 : 954081199.4951000000           : 954081199.4951
    6 : 954081199.495100000            : 954081199.4951
    7 : 954081199.49510000             : 954081199.4951
    8 : 954081199.4951000              : 954081199.4951
    9 : 954081199.495100               : 954081199.4951
   10 : 954081199.49510                : 954081199.4951
   11 : 954081199.4951                 : 954081199.4951
   12 : 9449546861.291050000000000     : 9449546861.29105
   13 : 9449546861.29105000000000      : 9449546861.29105
   14 : 9449546861.2910500000000       : 9449546861.29105
   15 : 9449546861.291050000000        : 9449546861.29105
   16 : 9449546861.29105000000         : 9449546861.29105
   17 : 9449546861.2910500000          : 9449546861.29105
   18 : 9449546861.291050000           : 9449546861.29105
   19 : 9449546861.29105000            : 9449546861.29105
   20 : 9449546861.2910500             : 9449546861.29105
   21 : 9449546861.291050              : 9449546861.29105
   22 : 9449546861.29105               : 9449546861.29105
   23 : 9752031802.626950000000000     : 9752031802.626951
   24 : 9752031802.62695000000000      : 9752031802.626951
   25 : 9752031802.6269500000000       : 9752031802.626951
   26 : 9752031802.626950000000        : 9752031802.626951
   27 : 9752031802.62695000000         : 9752031802.626951
   28 : 9752031802.6269500000          : 9752031802.626951
   29 : 9752031802.626950000           : 9752031802.626951
   30 : 9752031802.62695000            : 9752031802.626951
   31 : 9752031802.6269500             : 9752031802.626951
   32 : 9752031802.626950              : 9752031802.62695
   33 : 9752031802.62695               : 9752031802.62695
Done
```

Revised Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas

def main():
    pandas.set_option('precision', 10)
    file_name = 'sample_1.txt'
    print ('Loading ' + file_name)    
    content_df = pandas.read_csv(file_name, delimiter='|', header=None, engine='c', skipinitialspace=True,skiprows=0,
                                 float_precision='high')
    num_rows = content_df.values.shape[0]

    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        lines_list = f.read().split('\n')

    f.close()
    rowcount = 0
    print('Row   : Raw Value' + ' '*22 + ': Pandas Value')
    while rowcount < num_rows:
        value_list = lines_list[rowcount].split('|')
        print('{0:5d} : {1} : {2}'.format(rowcount, value_list[2].ljust(30, ' '), content_df.iloc[rowcount, 2]))

        # print('row: ' + str(content_df.iloc[rowcount, 1]) + ': ' + str(content_df.iloc[rowcount, 2]) + ': ' + str(value_list[2]))
        rowcount = rowcount +1

    print ('Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```